# egrep -v match lines containing some same text on each line

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching, string-matching

So I have two files.

Example of file 1 content.

```
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000001
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000002
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000003
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000004
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000005
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000006
```

Example of file 2 content.

```
/n01/mysqlarch1/mysql-bin.000004
/n01/mysqlarch1/mysql-bin.000001
/n01/mysqlarch2/mysql-bin.000005
```

So I want to match based only on mysql-bin.00000X and not the rest of the file path in each file as they differ between file1 and file2.

Here's the command I'm trying to run

```
cat file1 | egrep -v file2
```

The output I'm hoping for here would be...

```
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000002
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000003
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000006
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compare based on everything from `/`:

```
$ awk -F/ 'FNR==NR {a[$NF]; next} !($NF in a)' f2 f1
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000002
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000003
/n01/mysqldata1/mysql-bin.000006
```

#### Explanation

This reads file2 in memory and then compares with file1.

- `-F/` set the field separator to `/`.
- `FNR==NR {a[$NF]; next}` while reading the first file (file2), store every last piece into an array `a[]`. Since we set the field separator to `/`, this is the `mysql-bin.00000X` part.
- `!($NF in a)` when reading the second file (file1) check if the last field (`mysql-bin.00000X` part) is in the array `a[]`. If it does not, print the line.

---

> I'm having one problem that I've noticed when testing. If file2 is
>   empty nothing is returned at all where as I would expected every line
>   in file1 to be returned. Is this something you could help me with
>   please? –  user2841861.

Then the problem is that `FNR==NR` matches when reading the second file. To prevent this, just cross check that the "reading into a[] array" action is done on the first file:

```
awk -F/ 'FNR==NR && argv[1]==FILENAME {a[$NF]; next} !($NF in a)' f2 f1
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From `man awk`:

> **ARGV**
>
> The command-line arguments available to awk programs are stored in an
>   array called ARGV. ARGC is the number of command-line arguments
>   present. See section Other Command Line Arguments. Unlike most awk
>   arrays, ARGV is indexed from zero to ARGC - 1

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer.  I'm having one problem that I've noticed when testing.  If file2 is empty nothing is returned at all where as  I would expected every line in file1 to be returned.  Is this something you could help me with please?

Comment: nice to read that :) Remember you can accept the answer if it was helpful and solved the issue

Comment: I'm happy to do that.  Could you help take a look at one issue I've discovered?

Comment: @user2841861 uhms, tell me

Comment: I'm having one problem that I've noticed when testing. If file2 is empty nothing is returned at all where as I would expected every line in file1 to be returned. Is this something you could help me with please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87459/discussion-between-user2841861-and-fedorqui).